# Why does an instance of Test<?> accept non-null objects in the constructor?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

The *wildcard* `?` in *generics* represents an *unknown type* and accepts only `null`.
However, in the following example, the *constructor* accepts *(for example)* a `String` object, even though I have declared an instance of `Test<?>`.

```
public class Test<T> {
    private T object;
    public Test(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
    public void set(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<?> test = new Test<>("Test");    // compiles fine
        //test.set("Test");    // compiler error
    }
}
```

Why does this compile normally?

Comment: It's only a `Test<?>` on the LHS of the assignment. The expression on the RHS is a `Test<String>`.

Comment: In other words, what you have is equivalent to `Test<?> test = new Test<String>("Test");`

Comment: ‘And accepts only null’? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @user207421 It's true. The only valid value for `test.set()` would be `null`.

Comment: The `<>` asks Java to infer the type parameter of the type of the object being instantiated.  The type and type parameter of the variable being declared are *some* of the data feeding that inference, but not necessarily the *only* such data.  In this case, the type of the constructor argument factors in, too.

Comment: Yes, @shmosel, but it's unclear what the OP meant by that.  I took them to mean that `null` is the only value that variable `test` itself could take, which is clearly not true.

Comment: @shmosel Or a typecast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the constructor accepts (for example) a `String` object, even though I have declared an instance of `Test<?>`.

No.  You have declared a *variable* of type `Test<?>`.  You have created an *instance* of type `Test<X>`, for some `X` that the compiler is obliged to figure out for itself such that the overall statement is valid.  That is, here:

> ```
>         Test<?> test = new Test<>("Test");    // compiles fine
> ```

... the `<>` does not mean "copy the type parameter from the type of the variable" or anything much like that. `Test<?>` *is not* the type of the expression `new Test<>("Test")`.  That the chosen type parameter must make the type assignable to type `Test<?>` is one of the constraints that must be satisfied, but that's trivial, because any `X` will do for that.

Formally, Java will infer the most specific type parameter that satisfies all the constraints for the statement to be valid. `new Test<X>("Test")` is valid only for a relatively few `X`s:

- `java.lang.Object`
- `java.lang.Serializable`
- `java.lang.Comparable<String>` and a few other variations on `Comparable`
- `java.lang.CharSequence`
- `java.lang.constant.Constable` (since Java 12)
- `java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc` (since Java 12)
- `java.lang.String`
- intersection types of combinations of the above

`String` is the most specific of those, so it is the one chosen.

In practice, however, Java doesn't actually have to choose a specific type parameter at all.  It just has to satisfy itself that there is at least one that works.

---

The expression `test.set("Test")` is a different case.  It doesn't matter that the object assigned to `test` was inferred to have type `Test<String>`.  Here, as under all circumstances, Java analyzes the expression based on the *declared* types of any variables involved.  `test` is declared with type `Test<?>`.  There is therefore no type whatever that Java can be confident `test.set()` will accept as an argument. However, the value `null` is compatible with every reference type, so whatever the particular type parameter of the object `test` references might be, `null` is an acceptable argument to `test.set()`.